# Spring Security Thyemleaf page 403 after login using custom login page

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf

Im setting up a Web Application using thymeleaf and spring security username and password authentication. After my login is successful im redirected to a url but Im getting a 403 on that page. Below is my configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "index", "login", "/resource/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/userpage").hasRole("USER")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .defaultSuccessUrl("/userpage")
      .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
      .permitAll()
    .and()
      .logout()
      .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true")
      .invalidateHttpSession(true)
      .permitAll()
    .and()
      .csrf()
      .disable();
}
```

My User service

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
  User user = userRepository.getUserByEmail(username);
  if (user == null) {
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
  }
  log.info("loadUserByUsername() : {}", username);
  return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getId(), 
        user.getPassword(), getAuthority());
}

private List getAuthority() {
  return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")); // TODO
}
```

My Controllers

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login() {
  return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userpage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String userpage(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("user", new User());
  return "user-page";
}
```

I can see the user being authenticated when debugging `loadUserByUsername()`, but the page returns `There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).` Once im directed with `defaultSuccessUrl("/userpage")`

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible issue in the above code snippet is that, you have not provided `loginProcessingUrl()`. This is the place where Spring validates username and passwords

```
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "index", "login", "/resource/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/userpage").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage( "/myLoginPage" ) // Pointing to the controller method
        .loginProcessingUrl( "/authenticateTheUser" ) // No coding is needed. Spring will automatically handle this. 
        .defaultSuccessUrl( "/myFirstPage", true )
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();
```

Comment: after investigate more loginProcessingUrl() is what I was missing. After I sorted that my passwords were wrong. Looked like the password been used was the basic auth(33333-3333-3333-333) and not the BCrypt($245g45.g45g).  `return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getId(), 
        user.getPassword(), getAuthority());` had to be chaged to to `return new MyUser(user). Big thanks for the help

Comment: Anther problem im facing, is the role. I had to remove that to get it to work. Im currently investigating

Comment: As my understanding, by default roles should be stored in the database as `ROLE_USER`. With the prefix `ROLE_` if you are using Springs default `JDBC Authentication`.

Answer (score 1):

A 'loadUserByUsername(String username)' method is responsible for loading of credentials ( ex. from database ), not for authentication, presence of 'UserDetails' object does not mean that user with these credentials is authenticated and attached to current session.

1) Check that user's password is correct: Spring Security ( from 5)  uses by default BCrypt for passwords hashing, means stored password ( in database ) should be also a hash, not plaintext.

2) There could be a conflict with Basic authentication, so try to disable it by adding:

```
  .and().httpBasic().disable()
```

to security settings chain.

Comment: .and().httpBasic().disable() was part of the problem. Big thanks for helping me out